# Populate combobox from XML in XmlReader in C#

Tags: c#, xml, combobox, xmlreader

I have to read XML and populate combobox in C#. Here is what I tried:

```
private class Item 
{
  public string Name;
  public int Id

  public Item(string name, int id) 
  {
      Name = name; 
      Id = id;
  }
}
```

And here is my XmlReader code:

```
if (reader.IsStartElement())
{
    //return only when you have START tag
    switch (reader.Name.ToString())
    {
        case "Ad_Ref":
            Console.WriteLine("Name of the Element is : " + reader.ReadString());
            break;

        case "Ad_Id":
            Console.WriteLine("Your Id is : " + reader.ReadString());
            break;
    }
}
```

How I can do like this `comboBox1.Items.Add(new Item("Student 1", 1));`

My XML has only two tags, One is `Ad_Id` and other is `Ad_Ref`.

UPDATED: Here is XML Sample

```
<Listings>
 <Listing>
  <Ad_Id>1</Ad_Id>
 <Ad_Ref>admin</Ad_Ref>
  </Listing>
 </Listings>
```

Comment: can you share what's xml file like exactly

Comment: Why you are writing values to console?

Comment: This was just to know that i am getting values...Please ignor that and instead populate combobox

Comment: Create a `List<Item>` and bind it with `ComboBox`.

Comment: The issue is how to read XML and how to get First and Second values???

Comment: I think you need to use `while (reader.Read())` try it and put the `switch` case inside it. It should work that way and give you the values.

Comment: In Switch i get one value and in next switch i get other..how i can set both so that i set item and value in combo?

Comment: Do you want the combox to have only one value?? this doesn't make sence, but if you want to it any way, you can set the the combobox `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties to `Text` and `Value` repectivly then add the values you read to the items of the combox somthing like `comboBox.Items.Add(new { Text = refname, Value = id })` where the `refname` and `id` are the values you read in the switch clause.

Comment: Yes exactly i want like you mentioned...But Question is how i will get refname  and id in one case?Can you do that code for me?

Comment: You can't get it using one case. You hace to put two cases one for each tag and use `while`. If you want an easier way, you can get a list of `items` using LINQ to XML and then set the data source of the combo box from that list, instead of looping using `while` loop and the `switch` case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are opting for `XmlReader` you could do something like that:

[XmlReader.ReadToFollowing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162536(v=vs.110).aspx) is used to read the sibling element node.

```
var lstItems = new List<Item>();
using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)

            if (reader.Name == "Ad_Id")
            {
                reader.Read();
                string sAd_ID = reader.Value;
                string sAd_Ref = string.Empty;

                if (reader.ReadToFollowing("Ad_Ref"))
                {
                     reader.Read();
                     sAd_Ref = reader.Value;
                }

                 if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sAd_ID) && sAd_Ref != string.Empty)                        
                     lstItems.Add(new Item(sAd_Ref, Convert.ToInt32(sAd_ID)));
            }
     }
 }
```

You could populate `List<Item>` as `lstItems` above and bind it with ComboBox.

```
comboBox1.DataSource = lstItems;
comboBox1.DisplayMember="Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember="Id";
```

**UPDATE**:

Change access modifier of class to `public` and add property `getter` and `setter`.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Item(string name, int id)
    {
        Name = name;
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only give me error "Cannot bind to the new display member" on this line "comboBox1.ValueMember="Id""

Comment: Answer is updated. It was because you haven't mentioned get and set with properties.